# About FCM Multi-Subscription(Android)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I.m going to make the new Android app using Firebase Cloud Message  (topic system).
-Can I use Multi-subscribe systems(ex.topic1, topic2) in the android app?
-Can I see an example?
Does not matter Java or kotlin

Comment: I'm not sure what a multi-subscribe system is, but all about subscribing to topics is covered here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple#subscribe_the_client_app_to_a_topic

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.